# Python 3 key-sorted dict function not working correctly with PyQt4

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

I have a function which is supposed to sort a dict and print the result in a QTextEdit  box - "ADtext" in the  gui window.

Example dict:

```
lunch = {5: "14:00-16:00",27: "12:00-13:00", 13: "12:00-13:00"}
```

function:

```
    def example(self):
       keys= list(lunch.keys())
       keys.sort()
       for key in keys:
           self.ADtext.setText("({} => {})".format(key, lunch[key]))
```

However in the gui QTextEdit -"ADtext" box only one of the pairs is shown (always the same).

The function works without problems if I print the result in cmd (not in the QTextEdit box):

```
print ("({} => {})".format(key, lunch[key]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `append()` since `setText()` removes the previous text:

```
def example(self):
   self.ADtext.clear() # clean the previous text
   keys= list(lunch.keys())
   keys.sort()
   for key in keys:
       self.ADtext.append("({} => {})".format(key, lunch[key]))
```